# Ionic App build failed on iOS. Firebase Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRInstanceID'

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have an Ionic App that uses the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) plugin. I've managed to add the iOS platform by running `cordova platform add ios` and it adds the platform with no issues. However, when I try to run it on the simulator, it fails to build and it throws me this error.

[image]

This project is built by someone else and i'm simply trying to build the app for iOS devices. I hope someone would be able to help me on this.

**package.json**

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^5.21.6",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@rxjs/rx": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": "^0.12.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "ion2-calendar": "https://github.com/shaneparsons/ion2-calendar#76ae1e241183500a377647b363c931a03aa50bca",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.6.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-connection-service": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "26+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
        "ANDROID_FCM_VERSION": "21.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_BOM_VERSION": "26.0.0",
        "ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.4",
        "ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "4.1.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    ...
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="62158917" />
</widget>
```

Comment: FIRInstanceID is no longer part of Firebase.

Comment: So In that case, what do I do?

Comment: ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics  install this. I resolved my issue

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am bending over backwards...

Comment: @Haythem I know this is late. In order to solve this issue, you simply have to go to the code where the error is highlighted in Xcode which is seen in the first image above and simply delete that line of code. Rebuild the project and it should be successful